# random fortune on business cards

Tags: linux, latex

I have a latex business card template I am using, and I want to have the first line(s) be a fortune from the `fortune` command in Linux.

I have `fortune` installed. How can I have a different fortune on each business card? I print 10 to a page.

Tex file [here:](http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/polo/card.tex)

I have tried \immediate\write18{/usr/games/fortune > scriptoutput.tex} 
but the file never gets data put into it.

I am using texWorks, and have enabled Read, write, and execute scripts in the texworks preferences. 
so then i executed $fortune > scriptoutput.tex
and include \input{scriptoutput.tex} into the document.  which does get the text from scriptoutput.tex, and puts it into the business cards. Although every one of the cards is the same.

Comment: Have you enabled `--shell-escape`?